# Bluetooth hardware not detected in HP 4540s

Tags: windows-8

I have bought recently HP 4540s i3 with Windows, and didn't find Bluetooth hardware and driver.

Either it is not working or something else. Please tell me the solution  - what should I do? 
It is not in control panel option and not in device manager?

Comment: What bluetooth hardware?

Comment: Are you sure it has a Bluetooth option installed?  It appears to be optional or only on some models.  Exact HP model/SKU would clarify

Comment: I would imagine that Dave M is correct but the spec sheet doesn't list Bluetooth as "select models" or "windows 7 only". Seems like it should have either a broadcom or intel adapter.  http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3955552-3955552-5229455.html?dnr=1

Comment: This link seems to indicate some with BlueTooth and some without.  http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF25a/321957-321957-64295-3955552-3955552-5229455.html?dnr=1  There are likley a few variants and some pages indicate it can be installed by factory on special built models

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My device model is 4430s and I was just obsessed with the fact that it was said to come with Bluetooth and yet nothing showed up as a Bluetooth antena.

Later I decided to install Ubuntu, it was a surprise to see the OS recognize the Bluetooth antenna and start working. After returning to windows (Dualboot) it just seemed to start working.

Whenever I leave the device on in Linux (I currently work with Mint instead of Ubuntu) Windows is capable of recognizing it; on the other hand if left turned off, it disappears from windows.

1. Install Linux Mint from within windows (It gets installed as a
   software would).
2. Restart and booting in the Linux distribution.
3. Activate the Bluetooth antenna.
4. If none shows up then your model doesn't have that hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd> button on keyboard, type "add bluetooth" words and select "Settings" section from search results to find "Add bluetooth device" command.

Also mouse only method:

1. Open "Settings" icon in charms panel on the right edge of your screen.
2. Click "Change PC Settings"
3. Go to the "Devices" section and choose "Add a device"
4. Turn on pairing mode in your Bluetooth device and connect with it.

Or what you need to do?